# IRF1404 MOSFET fake?

Tags: mosfet

According to the data sheet these devices should be capable of handling 163A source to drain (though I have my suspicions that those little leads might not be up to that particular job).

I bought ten of these devices from China for just over two pounds sterling, which is already suspicious but cheap enough for tinkering. I want to switch short-circuit current from a 44Ah car battery for 100ms for the purpose of spot-welding tabs onto cells to make up batteries.

I put all ten MOSFETs in parallel and I got a couple of decent welds, but the third attempt shot the MOSFETs to pieces. Would I be correct in concluding that these Chinese IRF1404s are fakes? And if so, how can I be confident about procuring the genuine article?

Thanks for taking the time to read this.

Comment: How much current did you calculate is going through each MOSFET?

Comment: Also, what circuit are you using to drive the gate pins of the FETs? Editing your question to add a schematic would be useful here.

Comment: And add detailed information about run lengths and diameters of your wiring. Better add photos, too.

Comment: Can you control the pulse width down to 0.1ms ?

Comment: I didn't calculate current but rather followed the design of a spot welder that I'd seen on a YouTube video that looked like it did the job well. I assumed that this kind of load sharing would work okay -- Tony Stewart's answer is informative here but I will need time to study it. The timer is an off-the-shelf programmable circuit board that only goes down to increments of 100ms, so I used the shortest pulse it would give me. It has a low-side output switch so I had to use a MOSFET to make an inverter for driving the power-switching MOSFETs.

Comment: If you're interested in why the MOSFETs failed, you're going to need to show an actual schematic. Your description alone is too vague.

Comment: I don't see any provision for including links and photos, which I have ready.

Comment: Did you add any fly-back diodes?

Comment: There are no links and no photos.

Comment: Tony has answered my original question -- I'm clearly operating these MOSFETs out of spec. No flyback diodes. I can provide photos but it's not yet obvious to me how I might do this. Here is a link to the timer I'm using: https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Trigger-Cycle-Timer-Delay-Switch-12-24V-Circuit-Board-MOS-Tube-Control-Module/401288889293?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649

Comment: Did you ensure the current was EVENLY spread across all the FWTs?

Comment: I don't know what an FWT is but I went looking for the video that inspired me. I couldn't find that one but here is another where you can at least get the idea: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XJmQTgkeGc

Comment: Hey I just found this video and it explains the path I was trying to take... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6XTPPBLiYg

Comment: Andy Kay, if you are still monitoring, you should mark Tony's answer as accepted, since you seem to be happy with it.

Comment: Forgive me Keith but I'm not familiar with this site and I'm failing to see a "mark an answer as accepted" button. Where will I find this please?

Answer (score 3):

The challenge is to determine the Energy needed to make a reliable weld. (Joules)  Often these are made with Ultrasonic welds to avoid sparks with hydrogen gas.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftwXr4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

One can use a low side switch that does not exceed the Safe Operating Area (SOA) of a single device.  Putting ganged devices does not assume they will share current equally as there are many factors to consider.

Using a battery only with a timed pulse is possibly exceeding the maximum current of the FET's  with the battery rated for say 700 CCA at 0 degrees and possibly 900A at room temp.

A better way might use a very low ESR Super Cap rated for >=15V.

If we assume from the geometry that 1 weld was successful with 0.5 Joules shared in each x 10 that >5 Joules is needed for the thickness of material and area of the weld.

Using some x Farad Supercap may be a better solution with a halogen lamp that charges up the Cap between welds with some cold resistance that minimizes the current at the end of the discharge but provides a somewhat constant current flow to the cap to charge up in a reasonable time e.g. <= 5 seconds or as desired.

Assuming constant V for unknown time to get 5 Joules at 12V , what is C if 10 switches, cap and wire ESR = 1 mΩ ?
$$ E = ½CV²    $$ 
Imax = 12V/1mΩ = 12,000 Amps
C= 5J *2 /12²(V+) = 10/144 = 0.069 F
T=RC= 1mΩ * 0.069F =~ 0.07 ms  ( 70 us )
With 0.1uH of wire loop inductance ω²=1/(LC), f=ω/2π
 or  f=1/√(LC) = 12 kHz  so it is an overdamped pulse.

E = ½CV²

Below is just a switch shown where the Nfet can be connected. A mechanical switch would have to be rated for these surges would otherwise wear out fast if you plan on doing a lot. The tungsten contact requires a certain area and pressure to ensure a low resistance to improve power transfer efficiency where the resistance of the contact must be close to the switch loop resistance. (Max power transfer theorem)

Here is the SOA limits for that FET.  There is a high probability they were legit parts and you exceeded the SOA safe limit with 100ms. I would estimate it is be safe for 10A * 12V @ 100mS if they are shared equally.

[image]

Comment: Quick reply before I study your reply properly thanks Tony. I was using a bank of supercaps, each rated at 2.7V 500F (yeah right), and using a current-limiting buck converter to charge them. However, I found two of them to be faulty and ordered replacements. Whilst awaiting delivery I recruited the car battery with the aforementioned result.

Comment: Now you know how to compute energy  but how did you control pulse duration?

Comment: Thanks, I will study the information you have provided. I controlled the pulse duration with an off-the-shelf MOSFET timer that uses 100ms increments, so I went as low as I could go.

Comment: This commercial instrument has some additional useful information http://www.spotweldingconsultants.com/capacitive-discharge-welders/single-pulse-ins.htm

Comment: Tony, I can't thank you enough. I'm clearly operating these MOSFETs out of spec, and I need to retreat and reconsider. This is learning by play for me -- I've learned a lot and I'm loving it. Also thanks for the spot welders link.